# how to block Quickblox default users?

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I am creating iOS chat app, so i go for quickblox, I used sample chat demo app from quickblox, It lists some sample users and chat feature. I registered new app in admin panel and replaced my APP ID, Authorization secret, Account KEY , Authorization KEY in follwing lines

```
[QBSettings setApplicationID:kApplicationID];
[QBSettings setAuthKey:kAuthKey];
[QBSettings setAuthSecret:kAuthSecret];
[QBSettings setAccountKey:kAccountKey];
```

but still demo app list all other user not my own users created in admin panel? What i did wrong? How can we list our own set of users in app.

Also , We cant Chat to user from admin panel? Am i right? Is it any possible to make Admin to User chat?

Comment: are you login and signup with your userID

Comment: you mean in app? No

Comment: can use quickblox admin panel to get the above "application ID,autAuthKey and so on" and then will login to get the user list in your app.

Comment: Ok Thanks. i understand we can get user list by using our admin user id and password? I thought list may change based on APP ID.

Is it any possible to make Admin to User chat?

Answer (score 0):

You are still getting demo users because they're cached. Remove and install the app again, and if you have created users you will get them. In our chat sample we get users by tag 'dev'. So for quick testing you should create users with this tag. If you want to fetch all existing users you should change method `[[ServicesManager instance] downloadCurrentEnvironmentUsersWithSuccessBlock:^(NSArray *latestUsers)` with method

```
  //Getting all users
  QBGeneralResponsePage *page = [QBGeneralResponsePage responsePageWithCurrentPage:1 perPage:100];
  [QBRequest usersForPage:page successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBGeneralResponsePage *pageInformation, NSArray *users) {

       } 
   errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

  }];
```

Also check ability for retrieving users (take a look at [this question](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/issues/382))